Has Ubuntu broken my machine?
I have an HP Split x2 laptop supplied with Windows 8 and then upgraded to 8.1. All was well until I tried to boot it with a Ubuntu non-install USB stick, loaded with the latest Ubuntu iso using the latest version of Rufus. The boot process gave an initial 'Ubuntu - I'm busy loading' type screen and then locked up after 15 minutes of no further apparent progress. Having abandoned the idea, I tried to reboot Windows (remove USB stick / power down / power on) but I got the message 'selected disk image does not authenticate' and no further constructive progress could be made.
I booted the laptop using a generic Windows recovery USB stick (and, later, an HP equivalent made by this very laptop using the HP utility) and had options to run diagnostics, get system report, edit BIOS or run recovery. Running recovery gave me the same error message again, though the other functions behaved much as one would expect.
I suspect that the error message means "You don't seem to have permission to run Windows software on this machine" rather than "your system disc is corrupt". What can I do to persuade the boot processes that I'm the legitimate purchaser and owner of the machine which came with a paid-for copy of Windows 8.0? Or does the error message mean something else?

answer on the q: no. USB boot does NOTHING to the current OS. "What can I do to persuade the boot processes that I'm the legitimate purchaser and owner of the machine which came with a paid-for copy of Windows 8.0? " this is a windows question, windows problem so windows users might provide the answer.

Ubuntu USB after loading comes with 2 choices Try Ubuntu and Install Ubuntu.  Since you did not get to that part, there is nothing that Ubuntu USB could have done to your computer. Please check your bios for changes you may have done and check your hard drive health. Both of these questions can not be answered in this forum and if you have any more questions please read How do I ask a good question?.

The OP says it is not a boot media.

Thank you for your responses. I now have a working solution as prompted by an answer to my internet search for the error message I was receiving 'selected disk image does not authenticate'.
I have altered the BIOS settings so that 'Secure Boot' is now disabled and 'Legacy Boot' is enabled. The laptop now boots up to Windows 8.1 as before, and can boot a recovery stick and seems ready to undertake recovery actions if requested.
